# Create automatic tasks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to make wordpress create automatic tasks from a text file and assign them to the users. Acctually the text file should be separated in paragraphs and each paragraph should be assigned to the users as a job. 
What can I do? Do we have a plugin for this process?

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far ? SO will not going to write a code for you.

Comment: Do you know any plugin doing this process? @Milap